Using flask-session, works locally but has trouble with the lack of filesystem on Google App Engine
first ever post here.
I'm learning about using Flask-session for my python/flask app that I run from Google App Engine.  Ive suffered a few times from the fact that GAE doesn't have the concept of a local file system and TBH I hate using the /tmp areas for any file transitions.
I'm using flask-session to manage the in app session data and I define this at the initiation of my flask app
app.config['SESSION_TYPE'] = 'cachelib'
app.config['SESSION_CACHELIB'] = FileSystemCache(cache_dir='/tmp/session')

This works fine locally testing (as I have a file system available).
The options for flask-session types are redis, mongodb etc etc.  Does anyone know if its possible to use GCP firestore (or firebase) to achieve this instead.  I believe its MongoDB behind the scenes but I cannot get it to work.
Finding session management a bit of a dark art at the moment!
Regards
Marc
Tried :
app.config['SESSION_TYPE'] = 'cachelib'
app.config['SESSION_CACHELIB'] = FileSystemCache(cache_dir='/tmp/session')


Most people use sessions that are built in to Flask (without the external Flask-session package) and store the data in a cookie.  Why doesn't that work for you?
